# Map returns different value for two equivalent keys

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a map which returns the expected mapping when using the same AuthToken it was keyed with. However, it returns null when using an equivalent AuthToken `authToken2`. I cannot think of any reason for this behavior and its driving me crazy. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
//initialize stuff
User user = new User("Test", "User",
"https://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~jwilkerson/cs340/tweeter/images/donald_duck.png");
AuthToken authToken = new AuthToken("key");
HashMap<AuthToken, User> loggedInUsersByAuthToken = new HashMap<>();
loggedInUsersByAuthToken.put(authToken, user);
AuthToken authToken2 = new AuthToken("key");

System.out.println("authToken equals authToken2? " + authToken.equals(authToken2));
System.out.println("value from authToken is null? " + (loggedInUsersByAuthToken.get(authToken) == null));
//unexpected behaivor
System.out.println("value from authToken2 is null? " + (loggedInUsersByAuthToken.get(authToken2) == null));
```

The System.out.println statements print out as follows:

```
    authToken equals authToken2? true
    value from authToken is null? false
    value from authToken2 is null? true
```

Comment: Do the two `AuthToken` objects give the same result for the `hashCode` method?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Welp I feel dumb. Thanks, that was the issue. HashMap...the answer was right there in the name. Its just weird that the javadocs say that for the Map.get method if the keys are equal according to Objects.equals() than they will return the same value, but at least now I know.

Comment: Yeah the trick is that the Javadoc for Object tells you that if you override `equals`, you generally need to override `hashCode` too, and it explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logic , `authToken` and `authToken2` are not similar objects but when you compare them it compares the key that's why true is given

But from point of view of the objets its different

The map takes an element with key an `AuthToken` , you feed it with an element with `authToken` , so when you try to compare it with the `authToken2` it's not found because its not equal to the given first element ` **( the 2 objects are not similar even with same "key" : try to hash the 2 objects and you'll see that you will get different hashes )**

Answer (score 0):

The method `.equals()` in java doesn't mean that both objects are the same, it could be the same reference or a self-implemented comparison method.

If they, being different created objects, are obtaining the `.equals()` as `true`, It does mean that there is a self-implemented comparison.

You are getting that response due that `authToken` and `authToken2` are not the same objects and they do not share the same hash value, so the hash map cannot find the hash value of `authToken2`in its keys list.